# XML Validation

Tags: java, schema, xml-validation

I want to validate an XML file against RELAXNG schema provided. Searching on the net gave me hints to create a Schema instance using SchemaFactory by providing the appropriate Schema Language.  So as per my requirement I used:

*SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.RELAXNG_NS_URI);*

But the following exception was thrown at run:

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SchemaFactory that implements the schema language specified by: http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0 could be loaded

at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance(SchemaFactory.java:207)*

I am using Java6 and observed that only 'W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI' works.  Rest all the schema URIs throws the similar exception.

I am fairly new to using the XML validation APIs. Can someone please provide me the appropriate usage in case I am not doing it correctly?

Thanks & Regards,
Keya

Answer (score 2):

RNG is poorly supported in Java APIs, it never really got traction. I know of no Java API implementations that handle it. I suggest converting the schema to XML Schema (using [Trang](http://code.google.com/p/jing-trang/) or similar) and then validating against that.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply.  I used as you suggested Trang to convert the rng to xsd.  But I get error running it. Following is the command with the error: 

$ java -jar trang.jar -I rng -O xsd config_schema.rng config_schema.xsd
 xml-validation/trang-20081028/config_schema.rng:1:1: fatal: Content is not allowed in prolog.
$

Can you provide me some suggestion on the above error?

Comment: Make sure there's no whitespace or comments between the start of the the file and the start of the schema definition.

Comment: Thanks. Apart from whitespaces I was also using the .rng extension instead of .rnc. Using the right extension converted the RNG Schema to XSD.

Answer (score 0):

RNG is not supported as widely as XML Schema. You should always think of using XSD first.

Comment: RNG is, however, an awful lot easier to write. It's a valid notion to write in RNG then convert to XSD later.

Comment: Actually, make that RNC (RelaxNG Compact) is the easy one

Answer (score 0):

[msv](https://msv.dev.java.net/) is in Java; I suppose it has a clear API you can use, but I've only ever used it on the command line and in scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Kohsuke Kawaguchi apparently wrote a adapter library for jaxp to use a relaxng validator, see [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/02/validate_xml_us.html) and [here](https://isorelax-jaxp-bridge.dev.java.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I've had success in validating a document against a XML-based RelaxNG Schema using Java 6, check out :

[How to validate an XML document using a RELAX NG schema and JAXP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541253/how-to-validate-an-xml-document-using-a-relax-ng-schema-and-jaxp)

Don't know if it's relevant, just pointing out :-).