# Using Jing with Google App Engine. Can't load SchemaFactory given Relax NG schema

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, schema, relaxng, jing

Okay, so here's the short of what I'm trying to achieve. I am developing a small Google App Engine application that generates XML given a particular object.

Now, I run into issues because I need to use a Relax NG schema and validate it against my Document object. This works fine on my local machine (Eclipse Helios Java EE, Mac OS X Snow Leopard, Google Web Toolkit 2.2.0, App Engine 1.4.2), but as soon as I deploy to App Engine, my code fails and throws an IllegalArgumentException.

The specific exception is this:

```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SchemaFactory that implements the schema language specified by: http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0 could be loaded
```

The specific line(s) of code that it is complaining about are the following:

```
  System.setProperty(SchemaFactory.class.getName() + ":" + XMLConstants.RELAXNG_NS_URI, "com.thaiopensource.relaxng.jaxp.CompactSyntaxSchemaFactory");
  SchemaFactory schemaFac = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.RELAXNG_NS_URI);
```

The last line is the line that throws the Exception.

I have tried looking online, and posted in several Google Groups, but no one came forth with an idea.

**Note:** I took the use of some of the above code from this example: [How to validate an XML document using a RELAX NG schema and JAXP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541253/how-to-validate-an-xml-document-using-a-relax-ng-schema-and-jaxp/2104332#2104332)

My suspicion is that App Engine is not loading Jing.jar for some reason. I don't know how I can check that it is/isn't.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I actually found a workaround of sorts that completely takes out the (practically hackish) use of System.setProperty.

It turns out that Jing has a little class called "CompactSyntaxSchemaFactory".

Here is how I used it:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = null;

    CompactSyntaxSchemaFactory scReader = new CompactSyntaxSchemaFactory();
    URL relaxSchemaURL = new URL("http://example.com/myschema.rng");
    Schema2 relaxSchema = scReader.newSchema(relaxSchemaURL);

    docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    docFactory.setSchema(relaxSchema);
```

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

This post just to clarify.

The usual way I would validate an XML document with Jing and Relax NG is:

```
System.setProperty(SchemaFactory.class.getName() + ":" + XMLConstants.RELAXNG_NS_URI, "com.thaiopensource.relaxng.jaxp.XMLSyntaxSchemaFactory");
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.RELAXNG_NS_URI);
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File("path/to/schema.rng"));

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
```

Now, in App Engine, the first two lines don't work, and cause an IllegalArgumentException to be thrown, like you said. So exchanging them with

```
SchemaFactory factory = new XMLSyntaxSchemaFactory();
```

does the trick. Summary (including imports):

```
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;
import com.thaiopensource.relaxng.jaxp.XMLSyntaxSchemaFactory;

SchemaFactory factory = new XMLSyntaxSchemaFactory();
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File("path/to/schema.rng"));

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
```

Note that this is for schemas in XML syntax. For compact syntax, exchange XMLSyntaxSchemaFactory with CompactSyntaxSchemaFactory.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that `System.setProperty()` is failing, or rather not being used correctly. According to [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Environment):

> All system properties and environment variables are private to your application. Setting a system property only affects your application's view of that property, and not the JVM's view.

If SchemaFactory is part of the JDK (which I think it is), you may not be able to reset it.  However, you may have more luck setting the system property in your [appconfig file](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#System_Properties_and_Environment_Variables), as this might get changed earlier in the startup sequence.

Comment: Hmm... That may indeed explain it. I found a work around that I have posted.